# Does Mono used in Unity support arm64 on Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mono, arm64

If yes, is Mono JIT version? (I need libmono.so library).

Answer (score 1):

No, IL2CPP is used as a Unity backend for Android ARM64 targets.